# How can I give the same figure number to five different figures on five different pages?

Tags: floats, numbering

How can I give the same figure number to five different figures on five different pages using latex? For example, fig. 1.1, fig. 1.1 cont'd (player I), fig. 1.1 cont'd (player II), fig. 1.1 cont'd (player III), fig. 1.1 (player IV).

Comment: Check out the `\ContinuedFloat` command in the `subfig` package.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\ContinuedFloat` command from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package; using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` you can customize the format for the lable to include, for example, "(Continued)"; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{continued}{#1~#2 (Continued)}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=continued}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{First part of a figure}
\end{figure}               

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
B
\caption{Second part of a figure}
\end{figure}               

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
C
\caption{Third part of a figure}
\end{figure}               

\end{document}
```

[image]